# Not able add aspx view in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following the steps ->

New Project->ASP.NET Web Application->Empty Template->Reference and folders(Web Forms) for create new project

While adding View I can not find view engine options.(by default it creates .cshtml file)

Please guide where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to add like this :

```
Right Click Solution Folder i.e. Views --> Add --> New Item ... --> Web Form
```

Comment: while execution it gives below error:  The view at '~/Views/Home/Login.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.